# jQuery timer function tables

Tags: jquery, variables

So I want to make it so that one of `.achivement__card` in order gets the class `.active__card` **every 3000ms** and then start over again. When one gets class other shouldn't have it.

```js
$(document).ready(function ($) {

   setInterval(function () {
         moveActiveSelector();
     }, 3000);

  var curentActive = 0;

  function moveActiveSelector() {
        $(".achivement__card").val(curentActive + 1);
        $('.achivement__card').removeClass("active__card");
        $('.achivement__card').eq( curentActive ).addClass("active__card");
    };
});
```

```html
<div class="achivements">
    <div class="achivement__card"></div>
    <div class="achivement__card"></div>
    <div class="achivement__card"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.val()` only applies to input elements, not DIV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(".achivement__card").val(curentActive + 1);` doesn't do anything useful, DIVs don't have values.

You need to increment `curentActive` to add the class to the next element.

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {

  setInterval(function() {
    moveActiveSelector();
  }, 3000);

  var curentActive = 0;

  function moveActiveSelector() {
    $('.achivement__card.active__card').removeClass("active__card");
    curentActive++;
    if (curentActive >= $('.achivement__card').length) {
      curentActive = 0;
    }
    $('.achivement__card').eq(curentActive).addClass("active__card");
  };
});
```

```css
.active__card {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="achivements">
  <div class="achivement__card active__card">1</div>
  <div class="achivement__card">2</div>
  <div class="achivement__card">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank tou su much, i was searching this for a while. I just try to learn js, didn't know that.
Again thank you so much !!!